# Newtonsoft.Json nested deserialization doesn't create correct object type when type of property is "object"

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have a set of nested .net classes, with different types and inheritance. It tries to imitate a row collection of items. One of the classes is a Cell class, which contains a Value property of type object (anything can go here, even other nested Cells or Rows). 
The Cell and Row classes inherit from a base ItemComponent class (composite pattern)

I've created a custom converter to support this, and I get deserialized the correct object type, after using the TypeNameHandling to All

The problem I'm having is with nested Cells. When there's a Cell that has a value which is another cell or row, into the Value property I just get the string representing it, instead of the serializer populating the values. Here's my code so far

```
    public static object FromJson<T>(this string obj, T outputType)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj, outputType as Type, new JsonConverter[1] { new ItemComponentJsonConverter() });
    }

public abstract class CustomJsonConverterBase<T> : JsonConverter
{
    protected abstract T Create(Type objectType, JObject jsonObject);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var typeName = Type.GetType(jsonObject["$type"].ToString().Substring(0, jsonObject["$type"].ToString().IndexOf(',')));
        var target = Create(typeName ?? objectType, jsonObject);
        serializer.Populate(jsonObject.CreateReader(), target);
        // this is my attempt to make it work, but it doesn't. on first iteration it's populated, then I get a JObject with text again, and again
        if (target is Cell && (target as Cell).Value is JArray)
        {
            var innerCell = (target as Cell).Value.ToString().Substring(1, (target as Cell).Value.ToString().Length - 2).FromJson(typeof(Cell));
            (target as Cell).Value = innerCell;
        }
        return target;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}

public class ItemComponentJsonConverter : CustomJsonConverterBase<ItemComponent>
{
    protected override ItemComponent Create(Type objectType, JObject jsonObject)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(Row))
        {
            return new Row();
        }
        if (objectType == typeof(Entity))
        {
            return new Entity();
        }
        if (objectType == typeof(Cell))
        {
            return new Cell();
        }
        return (ItemComponent)Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
    }
}
```

Basically I'd like that when i get something like this (i've made it shorter) I get the correct structure

Cell
  .Value -> Entity
              .childItems
                  Row
                     .childItems
                          Cell
                              .Value -> 124

and so on

```
{
  "$type": "Arda.Lib.Models.Core.Cell, Arda.Lib",
  "childItems": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Arda.Lib.Models.Core.ItemComponent, Arda.Lib]], mscorlib",
    "$values": []
  },
  "Value": {
    "$type": "Arda.Lib.Models.Core.Entity, Arda.Lib",
    "childItems": {
      "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Arda.Lib.Models.Core.ItemComponent, Arda.Lib]], mscorlib",
      "$values": [
        {
          "$type": "Arda.Lib.Models.Core.Row, Arda.Lib",
          "childItems": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Arda.Lib.Models.Core.ItemComponent, Arda.Lib]], mscorlib",
            "$values": [
              {
                "$type": "Arda.Lib.Models.Core.Cell, Arda.Lib",
                "childItems": {
                  "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Arda.Lib.Models.Core.ItemComponent, Arda.Lib]], mscorlib",
                  "$values": []
                },
                "Value": 124,
                "Id": 247,
```